# AWS SES SDK in MongoDB Atlas App Service: TypeError during email send

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to send an email using the AWS SES SDK within a MongoDB Atlas App Service. My credentials and SES-Identities seem to be set up correctly. However, when I make the API call to send the mail, I encounter an error.

Here's the code I use to send the email:

```
const { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-ses");
const SES_CONFIG = {
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: context.values.get("SES-AccessKey-Value"),
      secretAccessKey: context.values.get("SES-SecretAccessKey-Value")
    },
    region: 'us-west-2',
};

const sesClient = new SESClient(SES_CONFIG);

const params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: ["xxx@xxx.xxx"],
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Charset: "UTF-8",
          Data: "New Test email text"
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: 'Test email'
      }
    },
    Source: "xxx@xxx.xx",
};

const command = new SendEmailCommand(params);
try {
    const response = await sesClient.send(command);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`Invitation send error:${error.name} - ${error.message}`);
    console.log(`Invitation send error:${error.stack}`);
    console.log(`Invitation send error:${error.$response}`);
    return { error: false, error: error.message };
}
```

Upon execution, the email is send correctly, but I get the following error message:

```
"Invitation send error:FunctionError -  FunctionError: TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined\n  Deserialization error: to see the raw response, inspect the hidden field {error}.$response on this object.",
"Invitation send error:Error\n\tat native\n ",
"Invitation send error:undefined "
```

Any pointers on what could be the root cause? And how can I resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance!